# How do I fix this error: cannot find -lglfw3 (Open Gl)

Tags: opengl

I encountered this error when executing the `make` command

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target '../bin/wrapmodes' failed
make[2]:  [../bin/wrapmodes] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all' failed
make[1]:  [CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make:  [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing linking to `glfw` instead of `glfw3`.

That solution worked for me when ran into this same issue trying to build a Code::Blocks project from a Windows setup. Additionally, I think you also must link against `GL` instead of `opengl` or `opengl32` (not sure if that applies to you or not).

Answer (score 0):

For the openGL SuperBible when I run `cmake` from build directory:

```
cmake ..
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/michael/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:315 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when                                                                                               
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the                                                                                        
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.                                                                                                 

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:                                                                                                                        

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so                                                                                                           

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:                                                                                                                           

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so                                                                                                   
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so                                                                                                         

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for                                                                                              
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.                                                                                       
Call Stack (most recent call first):                                                                                                                                
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)                                                                                                                                  
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.                                                                                               

-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'glfw3'
--   Found glfw3, version 3.3.2
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/build
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

When i run `make`:

```
make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sb7
[  5%] Built target sb7
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target alienrain
[  6%] Linking CXX executable /home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/bin/alienrain
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/build.make:98: /home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/bin/alienrain] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:275: CMakeFiles/alienrain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

From cmke dump the system found glfw3, so I had to find where -lglfw3 was being used in the make sequence, so I went into `/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/build/CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/` and since it was a link error I clicked on the link.txt and got something like:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -fopenmp -D_LINUX -std=c++0x -rdynamic CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o -o /home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/bin/wrapmodes   -L/home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/michael/Documents/OpenGL/SuperBible/sb7code-master/lib lib/libsb7.a -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lGL -lrt -ldl
```

I replaced -lglfw3 with -lglfw for all folders and link.txt files
and ran `make` and all the files make-d/built.

I had to copy over the media files into `/bin/media`.

When I went into the bin folder and clicked on depthclamp. I got
a running program!. I quickly browsed the files/binaries and ran several with shaders and textures and noticed that they ran.